# Mongo - how can I save documents that have periods in their field names?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I documents of the following form that I need to store in my Mongo database:

```
{
    "a.1": 1,
    "b.2": [
        {"c.3": 3},
        {"d.4":4}
    ]
}
```

When I try to insert documents like this into Mongo it objects because Mongo doesn't allow periods in field names.  How can I get around this limitation most intelligently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted MongoDB does not allow this because it is reserved for ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) which is a form for acessing "sub-field" information in either a plain sub-document or array member. Considering the following:

```js
{
    "a": {
       "b": 1,
       "c": 2
    },
    "d": [{ "e": 1 },{ "e": 2 }],
    "f": ["a","b","c"]
}
```

Where to set a value for field "b" under field "a" you would do:

```js
db.collection.update({},{ "$set": { "a.b": 2 } })
```

And many other uses. Particularly useful in a **`$set`** operation or with other update operators as this allows a singular element such a "a.b" to be set here without overwriting the entire content of "a", such as

```js
db.collection.update({},{ "a": { "b": 2, "c": 2 } })
```

And many other useful things, matching and incrementing in position:

```js
db.collection.update({ "d.e": 2 },{ "$inc": { "d.$.e": 1 } })
```

Setting an indexed value of an array:

```js
db.collection.update({ }, { "$set": { "f.1": "d" } })
```

So in brief, I'ts taken so don't even try. Don't try to escape the "." because that will just bring you woes. If you need to then use something that is not reserved such as  a dash "-" or underscore "_".

Really not sure to your purpose. Personally I camelCase just about everything by habit. The only other comment is that if you are trying to do some sort of "versioning" then you are going about it the wrong way. That should be part of "data" and not the field name. MongoDB does not like field names altering all over the place. So though "flexible" on schema, you should keep things more or less the same.

Comment: Thanks - very helpful.  The periods aren't coming from me -- they're already in the documents that are arriving from another API and I would like to preserve these documents in the exact form that I receive them, which it appears I will unfortunately not be able to do.

Comment: Nothing stopping you just preserving the entire document as plain text in it's original form. It's just that you cannot "do anything" real with the data in a MongoDB way, so you translate a copy and structured fields. Been doing this with XML responses and relational databases for years.

Comment: It's original form is not plain text -- it's a structure as described.  There is a point in my process where I am just serializing the whole thing to JSON text, though.

Comment: @JonCrowell If you are reveiving JSON from an external API then it's transmitted as text. Same for XML. That is what serialized means. If you have this is some other "binary" form then you can just stuff that into Mongo as well. I've basically said, store it how you got it **and** then parse and structure the document for useful queries.

Answer (score 0):

> In some cases, you may wish to build a BSON object with a
>   user-provided key. In these situations, keys will need to substitute
>   the reserved $ and . characters. Any character is sufficient, but
>   consider using the Unicode full width equivalents: U+FF04 (i.e. “＄”)
>   and U+FF0E (i.e. “．”).

So you could use `\U+FF0E` for `.`.

```
db.collection.insert({"field\uff0ename": "value"})
db.collection.find({"field\uff0ename": "value"})
```

Comment: I'd be almost certain that would break in the near future even if it doesn't in some existing driver implementation already. I wouldn't be relying on different encoding to get me out of jail.

Comment: If properly implemented, i am sure which most of the drivers are, should check for reserved characters in the keys. This is the only approach documented by MongoDB themselves.But we can always ensure to avoid such type of field naming conventions.